# Mutable reference to an item using 'find' in Rust

Tags: rust

How can I get a mutable reference to an item found in a vector?

I've tried the following which works if I don't make the iterator mutable using `.iter()`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut wrong = -1;

    let working = match vec.iter().find(|&c| *c == 2) {
        Some(c) => c,
        None => &wrong
    };

    println!("Result: {}", working);
}
```

But when I try to get a mutable reference using a mutable iterator `.iter_mut()`,

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut wrong = -1;

    let mut error = match vec.iter_mut().find(|&c| *c == 2) {
        Some(c) => c,
        None => &mut wrong
    };

    println!("Result: {}", error);
}
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
>  --> src/main.rs:5:48
>   |
> 5 |     let mut error = match vec.iter_mut().find(|&c| *c == 2) {
>   |                                                ^-
>   |                                                ||
>   |                                                |hint: to prevent move, use `ref c` or `ref mut c`
>   |                                                cannot move out of borrowed content
> ```

I also tried to make the type in the closure mutable with `|&mut c|` but that gives the following error:

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>  --> src/main.rs:5:48
>   |
> 5 |     let mut error = match vec.iter_mut().find(|&mut c| *c == 2) {
>   |                                                ^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
>   |
>   = note: expected type `&&mut {integer}`
>              found type `&mut _`
>   = help: did you mean `mut c: &&&mut {integer}`?
> ```

Comment: With both `|ref c|` and `|ref mut c|` I get: [`error[E0277]: the trait bound \`&&mut {integer}: std::cmp::PartialEq<{integer}>\` is not satisfied`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e91fd4c62be532d70ef477d31a5a72e5&version=nightly)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rust's [`.find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) passes the callback the type `&Self::Item`, and since you are using `.iter_mut()`, you've created an iterator where each item is `&mut T`. That means the type passed to your `find` callback is `&&mut T`. To get that to typecheck, you can do either

```
vec.iter_mut().find(|&&mut c| c == 2)
```

or

```
vec.iter_mut().find(|c| **c == 2)
```

with the second one being preferable.

The error you are getting is because the middle-ground you've chosen by using `&c` would set `c` to a value of `&mut T`, and one of Rust's big rules is that multiple things can't own a mutable reference to an item at the same time. Your non-mutable case works because you *are* allowed to have multiple immutable references to an item.